# Session stateless vs stateful vs hybrid?

Tags: web-applications

been searching around but cant find answer, may i ask basic questions:

1. any downside of stateless app? especially over stateful app?

2. any web apps using stateless?

3. any "hybrid" apps? example for the "cart" they use stateful, other service stateless.

Reason i ask:

1. i only know stateful benefits are : smaller message transmitted, apps may use the session state information(s).

2. if stateless really better, then why internet banking mostly (still) use stateful? (i tried by switching to different wifi)

3. some said for "cart" feature, we need stateful. But e-commerce mobile apps, although they use stateless, but they can maintain my "cart" in mobile as well on web browser, does it mean they use "stateful" on the "cart" ?

Appreciate any enlighten

Thanks in advance

Comment: Normally I would just edit your question and remove the "basic" tag because basic refers to the BASIC programming language, but it would leave this question with no tags at all.  I have no suggestions as to what tag(s) to add, but you're not going to get an answer with this tag.  Please replace it with something else.

Comment: Any application that has a database has state. It's not really possible to build many things without state. I suspect you have a much narrower definition of what you consider statefull/stateless but your question doesn't describe that well. What do you mean with stateless / stateful?